# template might not exist or might not be accessible

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have been trying to use thymeleaf layout dialect with spring mvc as mentioned in https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect. My spring-servlet as below

```
<beans:bean id="templateResolver"
  class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
  <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
  <beans:property name="suffix" value=".html" />
  <beans:property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
  <beans:property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
  <!-- These lines add the dialect to Thymeleaf -->
  <beans:property name="additionalDialects">
    <beans:set>
      <beans:bean class="nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.LayoutDialect" />
    </beans:set>
  </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
  <beans:property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</beans:bean>
```

I have kept all the template file in /WEB-INF/templates/. When I use following code to create and use tempting in thymeleaf

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    layout:decorator="Layout.html">
```

I get following error:

```
[THYMELEAF] * Dialect [1 of 2]: org.thymeleaf.spring3.dialect.SpringStandardDialect
[THYMELEAF]     * Prefix: "th"
[THYMELEAF] * Dialect [2 of 2]: nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.LayoutDialect
[THYMELEAF]     * Prefix: "layout"
[THYMELEAF] TEMPLATE ENGINE CONFIGURED OK
19:32:40,992 INFO  [org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) [THYMELEAF] TEMPLATE ENGINE INITIALIZED
19:32:41,199 ERROR [org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) [THYMELEAF][http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1] Exception processing template "home": Error resolving template "Layout.html", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (home:4)
19:32:41,202 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/expensemanager].[appServlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet appServlet threw exception: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "MainLayout.html", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (home:4)
```

If I don't layout:decorator="Layout.html" code works perfectly without any error.

Below is the image which shows my project structure

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this:

```
<beans:bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
  <beans:property name="templateEngine">
    <beans:bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
      <beans:property name="additionalDialects">
        <beans:set>
          <beans:bean class="nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.LayoutDialect" />
        </beans:set>
      </beans:property>
      <beans:property name="templateResolvers">
        <beans:bean class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
          <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
          <beans:property name="suffix" value=".html" />
          <beans:property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
        </beans:bean>
      </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
  </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

If this does not work, can you post a screenshot of the file and folder structure?

Comment: I tried your configuration but still facing same error. I have added project structure in post as you asked for. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Your HTML file has `layout:decorator="Layout.html"` but the file in the folder structure is called `MainLayout.html`.  Is there a mismatch somewhere?  If you can upload this sample project somewhere I can take a look.  I think there is some simple misconfiguration somewhere.

Comment: I have copied war file at https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EA49CD7184E0E40!172&authkey=!AI9iSfzen4xbBFw&ithint=file%2cwar please have a look at it and tell me if I misconfigured something...

Comment: In `home.html`, change `layout:decorator="MainLayout.html"` to `layout:decorator="MainLayout"`.  In `MainLayout.html`, change `layout:decorator="defaultLayout.html"` to `layout:decorator="DefaultLayout"`.  Basically, you have to simply provide the view name, not the file extensions.  You have already configured the file extension in the Spring configuration as `.html`.  Also make sure that names have the correct case or else your app will not work on Linux.